# How do I select all records from MYSQL table on with a LEFT JOIN where id not in column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I only want to select records from it where the record id doesn't exist in another table.

Here are my tables:

`staff` table:

[image]

and my `staff_to_assessors` tables

[image]

What I want to do is select all records from the users table who's id doesn't exist in the `staff_to_assessors` table.

So far I have:

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN staff_to_assessors s2a 
ON u.id = s2a.staff_id WHERE u.id NOT IN...
```

I am stuck on the last bit! Can somebody help
Thanks

Comment: Please provide DDLs (or an sqlfiddle), not pictures. But this is colloquially referred to as an 'exclusion join'.

Comment: you might try using a subquery? `WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM staff_to_assessors)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no match is found against a left join, you will receive a null staff_id.

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN staff_to_assessors s2a ON u.id = s2a.staff_id 
WHERE s2a.staff_id IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
WHERE u.id NOT IN(SELECT staff_id FROM staff_to_assessors)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer. I still seem to be getting a record returned though that shouldn't be.

Comment: The only difference being that the record that shouldn't be being return comes with it's staff_id field filled with it's id. ie = [staff_id] => 22

Answer (score 0):

Check for null id on the assessors table:

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN staff_to_assessors s2a 
ON u.id = s2a.staff_id 
WHERE s2a.staff_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @UrGuardian4ngel stated but here is the whole query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `users`
WHERE
    `users`.`id` NOT IN (
        SELECT
            `staff_to_assessors`.`staff_id`
        FROM
            `staff_to_assessors`
    )
```